# Ошибка при создании bean-компонента с именем webSecurityConfig: неудовлетворенная зависимость, выраженная в поле userSevice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Я хотел сделать рассылку писем пользователям по электронной почте и активировать учетную запись на Spring Boot. И когда я запускаю приложение, оно выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-03 11:40:31.737 ERROR 10104 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSevice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userSevice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in com.example.eight.repo.UserRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.eight.models.User com.example.eight.repo.UserRepo.findbyActivationCode(java.lang.String)! No property findbyActivationCode found for type User!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.example.eight.EightApplication.main(EightApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.example.eight.config;

import com.example.eight.service.UserSevice;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class  WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserSevice userSevice;

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/registration", "/static/**", "/activate/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSevice)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.example.eight.service;

import com.example.eight.models.Role;
import com.example.eight.models.User;
import com.example.eight.repo.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.thymeleaf.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
public class UserSevice implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private  MailSender mailSender;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public boolean addUser(User user){
        User userFromDb = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDb != null){
            return false;
        }
        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        userRepo.save(user);

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())){
            String message = String.format(
                    "Hello, %s! \n"+
                            "Welcome to Spring. Please, visit next link: http://localhost:8080/activate/%s",
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getActivationCode()
            );
            mailSender.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", message);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean activateUser(String code){
        User user = userRepo.findbyActivationCode(code);
        if(user == null){
            return false;
        }

        user.setActivationCode(null);
        userRepo.save(user);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Repository: UserRepo.java

```
package com.example.eight.repo;

import com.example.eight.models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findbyActivationCode(String code);
}
```

MailSender.java

```
package com.example.eight.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MailSender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String message){
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        mailMessage.setFrom(username);
        mailMessage.setTo(emailTo);
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(message);

        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }

}
```

MailConfig.java

```
package com.example.eight.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class MailConfig {
    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.mail.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${mail.debug}")
    private String debug;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getMailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        javaMailSender.setPort(port);
        javaMailSender.setUsername(username);
        javaMailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties properties = javaMailSender.getJavaMailProperties();

        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol",protocol);
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", debug);

        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
    User findbyActivationCode(String code);
}
```

Синтаксическая ошибка в `findbyActivationCode`, `By` должно начинаться с заглавной буквы.